# Why do I get the error: "Class is not key-value coding compliant for key major" even though major is a property of the class?

Tags: swift, xcode, nsarray, key-value-coding

I am attempting to use NSArrays and NSPredicates to filter certain cells of a UITableView. I have a TableViewController class called FilterTable that is made up of FilterCell, which is a subclassed UITableViewCell. The data in a filter cell comes from a UserProfile, which has a property "major". When the user clicks a button, I want the table to show only the cells that correspond to users that have Computer Science as their major. I made an NSPredicate to filter the array of UserProfile that I use to populate my table, but when I do this I get the error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key major.'

However, as I said major is a property of UserProfile.

Other fixes to keyvalue compliancy issues suggest that outlets are not connected correctly in interface builder. However, UserProfile is not directly shown on FilterTable and is therefore not connected through IB, nor do I want it to be. Instead FilterTable has an array of UserProfiles which it uses to populate FilterCells. I also tried linking the FilterCell to FilterTable and then I could access the label corresponding to major, but that gave me an error that you cannot make an outlet to repeating content.

```
// FROM FilterTable:
...
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "major = 'Computer Science'")
filteredProfiles = (userProfilesArray as NSArray).filtered(using: predicate) as NSArray
...


// FROM UserProfile
class UserProfileViewController: UIViewController {
var major: String!
...
```

Comment: Why not the Swift way `userProfilesArray.filter{$0.major == "Computer Science"}`? Don't use `NSArray` in Swift anyway. You throw away the type information. But according to the code the `major` property is part of a **contoller** but it should be a part of the **model** (the type of `userProfilesArray`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified yet the element that has the major property, try this...

```
userProfilesArray.filter{$0.major == "Computer Science"}
```

assuming that your array is an Array of Profile objects

Comment: great, thank you! For future use, what does the $.0 notation mean?

Comment: are called Shorthand Argument names, is the element in the closure...  in a for loop... 
for item in items {
}
It will be the equivalent of **item**

Comment: Ultimately I would like to use NSFetchRequest to query information from a database, which is why I was trying to use an NSPredicate now. However, I can't seem to adapt your answer to use NSPredicate. I tried NSPredicate(format: "$0.major = 'Computer Science'") but the format string cannot be parsed. How can I use this syntax with NSPredicate?

Comment: In the example used at this link (https://nshipster.com/nspredicate/) they use the same setup, where they declare a list of people and then filter using a predicate like: NSPredicate(format: property = value)

Comment: have you tried the string comparisons? also I noticed that your code uses = instead of ==